# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in SWIFT

Tags: swift, core-data

I am getting this wrapping error when I implement my fetched managed object core data code. I realise that it may be due to needing data in my managedObjectContext but that throws a lot more errors in my code.. any other ideas??

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

let ReuseIdentifierToDoCell = "ToDoCell"

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    // Initialize Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")

    // Add Sort Descriptors
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why your `managedObjectContext` is an implicitly unwrapped optional? (Just "It silences errors in my code" *isn't* a good reason) Where do you assign a value to it? You should only ever use implicitly unwrapped optionals with a great deal of care. My [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36360605/2976878) might be useful for helping you deal with optionals safely.

Comment: at what line in your code did you get that error?

Comment: at the let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedController

Comment: @Leanneheal That means your `managedObjectContext` is nil when you come to access it in your `fetchedResultsController` initialisation. You need to make sure it has a value before you access your `fetchedResultsController`. Although the safest solution is using a non-optional, and either providing it with a default value, or making it lazy.

Comment: Where/when do you set the managed object context in `ViewController`?

Answer (score 2):

No clue why everyone refuses to post an actual *answer* to the question.

Your variable `managedObjectContext` is `nil`.  You are probably not injecting it properly before this lazy variable is accessed.

Put a breakpoint on the error line and confirm that your `managedObjectContext` variable is `nil` then backtrace to find where you are supposed to be setting it.